# How to name a two word variable

Tags: naming

I'm not a native English speaker and I'm wondering how's better to naming a variable with multiple words.

For example, I have two urls. One is for querying and the other is for submitting.

Should them be named as url_query, url_submit? Or querying_url, submitting_url? Or query_url, submit_url? Or things like submission_url?

I prefer url_query and url_submit. They are neat if I have a lot different urls for different purposes. But it sounds strange if I say it out.

Comment: This site is for questions about actual code. I understand that what you are asking is related to coding, but it is not truly about code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a highly opinionated subject and  it may be best to consult a specific coding style of your choice.

However, in general you want you variable names to be easily understood and readable.

For this reason items such as `url_submit` and `url_query` may be better option, as both are fairly understandable.

There are many different naming conventions, but the most important factor here is readability and implementation. Remember that comments will also help the readability as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can name them however they feel right to you.  Typically I camelCase them however instead of using underscores.

submitUrls/queryUrls

Try to think globally however as you may have these replicated in other pages and you may be able to build off your existing names like *action/*Thing(ie submit + what to submit "submitUrls")

Also, If something doesn't seem to make a good deal of sense to you when you're naming it. It is wise to add a line of comments in to identify what this function does later down the road if you have a bunch of functions named of actions and items.(Things)